# jQuery get input val() from $("input") array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

I have a function that returns whether or not every text input in a form has a value.

When I first made the function it looked like this:

```
function checkInput(inputId) {
check = 0;          //should be 0 if all inputs are filled out
for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {   // get all of the arguments (input ids) to check
    var iVal = $("#"+arguments[i]).val();

  if(iVal !== '' && iVal !== null) {
    $("#"+arguments[i]).removeClass('input-error');
  }
  else {
    $("#"+arguments[i]).addClass('input-error');
    $("#"+arguments[i]).focus(function(){
      $("input").removeClass('input-error');
      $("#"+arguments[i]).off('focus');
    });
  check++;
  }

}

  if(check > 0) {
    return false; // at least one input doesn't have a value
  }
  else {
    return true; // all inputs have values
  }

}
```

This worked fine, but when I called the function I would have to include (as an arstrong textgument) the id of every input I wanted to be checked: `checkInput('input1','input2','input3')`.

---

Now I am trying to have my function check every input on the page without having to include every input id.

This is what I have so far:

```
function checkInput() {
  var inputs = $("input");
  check = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
      var iVal = inputs[i].val();

  if(iVal !== '' && iVal !== null) {
    inputs[i].removeClass('input-error');
  }
  else {
    inputs[i].addClass('input-error');
    inputs[i].focus(function(){
      $("input").removeClass('input-error');
      inputs[i].off('focus');
    });
  check++;
  }

}

if(check > 0) {
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
}

}
```

When I call the function it returns this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: inputs[i].val is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do inputs[i], this returns an html element, so it is no longer a jquery object. This is why it no longer has that function.

Try wrapping it with $() like $(inputs[i]) to get the jquery object, and then call .val() like:

```
 $(inputs[i]).val()
```

If you are going to use this in your for loop, just set it as a variable:

```
var $my_input = $(inputs[i])
```

Then continue to use it within the loop with your other methods:

```
$my_input.val()
$my_input.addClass()
```

etc..

Comment: Thanks. it works the way I want it to now. You were the first with a response so I'll give you the check mark.

Comment: Thanks @phprunner, understanding this will help you alot with your future jquery code. good luck man.

Answer (score 2):

if you use jquery `.each()` function, you can do it a little cleaner:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').on('click', function() {
        $('input').each(function() {
            console.log('what up');
            if($(this).val().length < 1 ) {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.input-error {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="submit">SUBMIT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very simple fix. You need to wrap you *jquery* objects within the *jquery* constructor `$()`

Such as for `inputs[i].val()` to `$(inputs[i]).val();`

Here is the full working example:

http://jsbin.com/sipotenamo/1/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly one of the things the [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method is for. Rather than using `inputs[i]`, use the following:

```
// Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.
inputs.eq(i)
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.eq()` method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, I would make use of the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function for looping through the form elements. This will be the modified code

```
function checkInput() {
        var $inputs = $("input"),
            check = 0;
        $inputs.each(function () {
            val = $.trim($(this).val());
            if (val) {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                $(this).focus(function () {
                    $("input").removeClass('input-error');
                    $(this).off('focus');
                });
                check++;
            }
        });
        return check == 0;
    }
```